# Check data if exist in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Good Day,

I was thinking about authenticating a user if he/she is voted based on their student_id. I tried retriving the data to the android studio but it always falls on the else.

Here is my code:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.voter_home:
                Fragment_Voter_Home fragment = Fragment_Voter_Home.newInstance(Pstud_no);
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.voter_fragment,
                        fragment).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_voter_ssc_president:
                userReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("vote");
                Query VerifySSCPresident = userReference.orderByChild("student_id").equalTo(Pstud_no);
                VerifySSCPresident.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        if (dataSnapshot.child(Pstud_no).exists())
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(Voter_Screen.this, "Already Voted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Voter_Screen.this, Voter_SSC_President.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
                break;
            case R.id.nav_voter_csc_president:
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(Voter_Screen.this, Voter_CSC_President.class);
                    startActivity(intent1);
                break;
        }

        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

Pstud_no is the current user.

This is my Firebase table.

[image]

Is there anything you can suggest to improve my code? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already querying for `Pstud_no`, you don't have to check for a `child` node with that key in the `onDataChange`. Instead you can just check if the query returned a data snapshot that exists:

```
Query VerifySSCPresident = userReference.orderByChild("student_no").equalTo(Pstud_no);
VerifySSCPresident.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            Toast.makeText(Voter_Screen.this, "Already Voted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Voter_Screen.this, Voter_SSC_President.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
    }
```

Comment: Hey man, your code works. My bad. orderByChild("student_id") should be orderByChild("student_no").

Comment: Good catch: the parameter in the code indeed needs to match the property name in the JSON. I fixed it in the answer.